# three.js BoundingBoxHelper without diagonals

Tags: javascript, three.js, bounding-box

My BoundingBox is like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGmxF.png and I don't want to show the triangles inside the box, how can I remove those lines? Thanks.

```
    var bbox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(object3d, new THREE.Color(0xFF9900));
    bbox.visible = false;
    bbox.name = "BBOX"
    bbox.update();

    object3d.children[0] = bbox;

    scene.add(bbox);
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: `BoundingBoxHelper` has been deprecated. You can now use this pattern:

```
// box helper
boxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper( parent );
boxHelper.material.color.set( 0xffffff );
scene.add( boxHelper );
```

In your render loop, you may have to do this:

```
boxHelper.update();
```

three.js r.85

Comment: I tried your code, and I don't know what's wrong... it doesn't do anything.

Comment: The box should be there, it just has size 1 x 1 x 1. Call `bbHelper.update()`.

Comment: `  var bbox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(object3d, new THREE.Color(0xFF9900));
        bbox.visible = false;
        bbox.name = "BBOX";
        scene.add(bbox);
        object3d.children[0] = bbox;

        var boxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(bbox); // to remove the diagonals
        boxHelper.material.color.set(0xff9000);
        scene.add(boxHelper);
        bbox.update();`

It doesn't work to me... It only shows the rectangle that I want, but when I click on the object, it shows me the diagonals..

Comment: Provide a simple example of your problem by editing [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/).

Answer (score 1):

Now [from three.js r72](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r72) there is [a `THREE.BoxHelper` class](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/BoxHelper) that is exactly what you need. It will give you a wireframe box without the diagonals:

```
var helper = new THREE.BoxHelper( object );

scene.add( helper );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a BoundingBox to get the dimensions of your scene and apply them to a `BoxGeometry` with a wireframe material. The `BoxGeometry` does not have the triangles inside.

Comment: Where shall I put this BoxGeometry?